# How to find the aggregate geographic distribution of bitcoin traders using a certain exchange?

Tags: exchanges, trading, adoption

I wonder whether it is possible. Are there any ways of doing this via e.g. somehow collecting the IP addresses of all traders on an exchange such as Bittrex?

Comment: 1. Question is offtopic 2. Still curious why you need this data? 3. There are lot of web analytics tools/websites available to check visits to any website by country. However lot of people use VPN so it's not 100% correct.

Comment: @Prayank: What makes this question off-topic?

Comment: Not sure. I consider it related to trading or spying or web analytics. Not related to Bitcoin.

Comment: Agree with @Prayank, this question is literally: "how to collect IP addresses of users of specific website". There are ways of connecting some bitcoin addresses with IPs mostly on basis of usage shitty spv, but this question isn't about bitcoin but exchanges.

Comment: So where should I ask this question?